# How do I calculate the electrical power of a BLDC motor?

Tags: power, brushless-dc-motor, calculation

I used a current sensor to measure the current of one of the motor phase lines (Iphase or Iline?), and used a voltage sensor to measure the voltage between two motor phase lines (Vline-line).

With these two values, how do I calculate the electrical power of the BLDC motor? They all are AC, but I don't know if I should use the formula of power calculation for WYE connection or DELTA connection.

Answer (score 1):

> *I don't know if I should use the formula of power calculation for WYE
> connection or DELTA connection*

If your motor is 3-phase then the load type (wye or delta) makes no difference if you use the "two wattmeter" method: -

[image]

[image]

Images from [here](https://circuitglobe.com/two-wattmeter-method-of-power-measurement.html)

In other words W1 + W2 = power for both configurations.

> *I used a current sensor to measure the current of one of the motor
> phase line (Iphase or Iline?), and use a voltage sensor to measure the
> voltage between two motor phase lines (Vline-line). With these two
> values, how do I calculate the electrical power of the BLDC motor?*

I think you will have difficulty using your method because it cannot account for the full device power. You can't even reliably scale-up the reading because, on many types of load at low power factors (less than 0.5), using the 2 wattmeter method can produce a negative power reading on one meter with the other power being positive. At exactly 0.5 power factor, one meter will read zero.